# Is it possible to make a transaction that depends upon another existing transaction?

Tags: transactions

Is it possible to make a transaction that only executes after another *existing* transaction executes?
E.g., if I have a transaction where the fee is too low, can I broadcast a trivial "depends upon" transaction with a higher fee to force the stuck transaction to get processed?

To be clear, I'm not asking about batch transactions - I'm asking whether one can depend upon a transaction that has already been broadcast.

Thanks!

Comment: Not natively, no. Might be possible with a smart contract, but execution can't cross blocks as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, execution here wouldn't cross blocks. Imagine there's a "stuck" transaction in the mempool, and it's been there for a few blocks. So I make a no-op transaction that depends on the stuck transaction, and they're both confirmed in the same block.

Comment: Tezos does not have this. Nor does tezos support modifying the fee once in the mempool. I believe there is a merge request for this already but I can't find it.